# Running Boost unit tests on different processes

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test, systemc

I want to do unit testing in a SystemC program. The idea is to have multiple test suites with several tests in each suite. Each one of the tests would require resetting the SystemC framework (e.g., by calling `sc_simcontext::reset()`), but that is actually not possible due to some bug that is apparently not going to be fixed anytime soon. Therefore, I decided to come up with a workaround.

I found out that if I run each test on a different process everything works fine. The following code snippet gives an overview of the scheme I used to make it work:

```
void test1() {
  // ...
  sc_start();
}

void test2() {
  // ...
  sc_start();
}

typedef std::function<void()> TestFunction;

void run_test(TestFunction test_function) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  switch (pid) {
  case -1:
    throw std::runtime_error("Error forking process");
  case 0:
    test_function();
    exit(0);
  default:
    waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
    break;
  }
}

int main() {
  run_test(test1);
  run_test(test2);
}
```

Now I want to implement such a testing scheme with Boost Unit Test.

I have been studying the internals of Boost Unit Test library and I have found that `unit_test_main` seems to be the function that triggers the execution of all the tests. But I could not devise a non-intrusive way to interact with Boost Unit Test in order to run each test on a different process.

Does anyone know of a simple solution for running each test on a different process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not 100% satisfied with the solution that I came up, but I will post it anyway. For convenience, I encapsulated everything into a namespace:

Header file:

```
namespace util {

typedef std::function<void()> TestFunction;

void run_test(TestFunction test_function);

} // namespace util

#define SYSTEMC_TEST_CASE(name)       \
  void name##_impl();                 \
  BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(name) {        \
    util::run_test(name##_impl);      \
  }                                   \
  void name##_impl()
```

Source file:

```
namespace util {

void run_test(TestFunction test_function) {
  pid_t pid = fork();
  switch (pid) {
    case -1:
      throw std::runtime_error("Error forking process");
    case 0:
      try { test_function(); }
      catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << boost::format("Exception caught: %1%") % e.what() << std::endl;
        exit(1);
      }
      catch (...) { exit(1); }
      exit(0);
    default:
      waitpid(pid, nullptr, 0);
      break;
  }
}

} // namespace util
```

Usage example:

```
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(suite)

SYSTEMC_TEST_CASE(test_case1) {
  // ...
}

SYSTEMC_TEST_CASE(test_case2) {
  // ...
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

`main.cpp` contains:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE TestModule
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <systemc.h>

boost::unit_test::test_suite* init_unit_test_suite(int, char*[]) {
  using namespace ::boost::unit_test;
  assign_op(framework::master_test_suite().p_name.value,
      BOOST_TEST_STRINGIZE(BOOST_TEST_MODULE).trim("\""), 0);
  return 0;
}

int sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(&init_unit_test, argc, argv);
}
```

Each test case will now be executed on a different process. Therefore, SystemC runs multiple times during a single execution without any problem.

The only real issue of this solution is that for some reason it is not possible to use a file sink when outputting XML results. But I have found that everything works fine if the sink is `stderr` and the output is redirected to a file.