# Does SystemC unit testing need forking?

Tags: systemc

I am starting with using SystemC, and studying example mentioned in 
[Using existing unit test frameworks with SystemC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923292/using-existing-unit-test-frameworks-with-systemc)

I do not really understand why forking is required, especially when one fork only waits the other. Is there something in the kernel that needs such multi-threading (especially the event handling)? (in other words: do I need this type of handling ONLY when I need concurrent testing, or also in the more simple cases)

Another question that in the linked answer I see the logo at the beginning

```
 SystemC 2.2.0 --- Feb 24 2011 15:01:50
        Copyright (c) 1996-2006 by all Contributors
                    ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
```

while in my case the logo is at the end of the output

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
Hello World.

        SystemC 2.3.1-Accellera --- Mar 28 2017 21:08:36
        Copyright (c) 1996-2014 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED
```

It is just because of the different versions, or it is an expected timely behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way SystemC kernel is designed in it's current form it does not fully support dynamic creation/removal of simulation module's, once you have started the SystemC simulation with `sc_start()` and stopped the simulation with `sc_stop()` you need to completely destroy the SystemC simulation context.

Kindly look at the updated answer for better solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806909/4690576).
**Note:** It is advisable to have separate executable for different simulation context as the simulator does not guarantee the results for the simulation in this kind of environment, kindly refer [SystemC LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1666/download/1666-2011.pdf) for more details.

As for the SystemC logo differences it is due to different buffering of `stdout`, `stderr` in your system. You will see different results for every execution of the binary. (If it is consistent then maybe google test framework is handling the `stdout` and `stderr` streams internally.)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with using registry design pattern. I have already posted how you can do that with SystemC and GoogleTest in [Using existing unit test frameworks with SystemC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47371857/8964181)